# Show Images From NonSecured site In Secured Site

Tags: ssl

We have a site which is running under SSL. But we have to show images and videos from some non secured sites. At present we are not able to show these images and videos. These non secured sites are running on the same server on which this secured site is running. Can any one please let us know how to solve this issue.

Regards

Tarunjit Singh

Answer (score 0):

If the non-secure sites are on the same server as the secure then just setup new aliases pointing to that content in the SSL Vhost and modify your references to point to the new SSL versions.

If you want to use SSL on site B with a reference to a non-SSL item on Site A you can't. You'll need to do the above or enable SSL on site A and update your references to that.